# There is no measure such that $\mu(\lbrace f : (f(t_1), ... , f(t_n)) \in A\rbrace) = \mu_{(t_1,...,t_n)}(A)$

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $C[0,\infty)$ denote the space of continuous functions $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{C} [0,\infty)$
denote the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $C[0, \infty)$ generated by sets of the form
$$
\lbrace f ∈ C[0,\infty) : f(t) ∈ A\rbrace,
$$
with $t\in [0,\infty)$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Find a consistent family of probability measures $\mu_{t}$
indexed
by finite sequences $t = (t_1,..., t_n)$ with $0\leq  t_1 < ... < t_n$ with the property that: there is no
measure $\mu$ on $C[0,\infty)$ satisfying
$$
\mu(\lbrace f : (f(t_1), ... , f(t_n)) \in A\rbrace) = \mu_{(t_1,...,t_n)}(A)
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, t_1 \leq ...\leq t_n$ and $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

My approach was thinking about properties of $C[0,\infty)$, because if this space would have been changed to just all functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then by Kolmogorov extension theorem there is no consistent family with the property above. Then it seems logical to think about sets like $\lbrace f\in C[0,\infty): f(q_i)=1 \mbox{ iff } q_i\neq 0, \mbox{ otherwise } 0\rbrace$, where $q_i$ is a sequence of all rationals and $r_i$ a sequence of real numbers.
This set is empty, but maybe this is a limit of a decreasing  sequence whose $\mu$ measure is not $0$ (for contradiction).

However, I cannot find such a family of measures. The one time it leads to non-consitency, the other time the limit set has $\mu$-measure $0$. Is there anyone who can find a good measure family? Thanks in advance.